# "org.apache.jasper.JasperException" after failing form validation

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I always get the following error when my form fails to validate:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'regform' available as request attribute

I don't get this error when the form input is valid. The root cause is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Neither BindingResult nor plain target
>   object for bean name 'regform'
>   available as request attribute

Here is `net.sandbox.controllers.RegistrationController` with the imports omitted for brevity's sake:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegForm(Model model) {
        RegistrationForm regForm = new RegistrationForm();
        model.addAttribute("regform", regForm);
        return "regform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(@Valid RegistrationForm regForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "regform";
        }

        userInfo.setUserName(regForm.getFirstName());
        model.addAttribute("regform", regForm);
        return "regsuccess";
    }
}
```

What does it mean?

---

**Update**: added requested JSP files.

`regform.jsp`

```
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="Registration" />
</jsp:include>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
        <h2>Register below.</h2>
        <form:form method="post" commandName="regform">
            <p><form:input path="firstName" /> <form:errors path="firstName" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" /></p>
        </form:form>
<jsp:include page="includes/footer.jsp" />
```

`header.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="userInfo" scope="session" class="net.sandbox.sessionbeans.UserInfo" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><%= request.getParameter("pageTitle") %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="float: left; width: 50%">Sandbox -- <%= request.getParameter("pageTitle") %></h1>
        <h4 style="float: left; text-align: right; width: 50%"><% out.print(userInfo.getUserName()); %></h4>
        <hr style="clear: both" />
```

`footer.jsp`

```
    <hr />
    <p><i>Copyright information goes here.</i></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post jsp page form tags

Comment: I added the JSP source for the form above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, in your `validateForm(..)` method you don't put a form backing object into the modelMap as soon as the form validation fails. If you would reorganize your code like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateForm(@Valid RegistrationForm regForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("regform", regForm);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "regform";
        }

        userInfo.setUserName(regForm.getFirstName());        
        return "regsuccess";
    }
```

you could solve your problem, but it is still not a optimal solution. Best practice is to use a method to populate form objects like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("regform")
public RegistrationForm populateForm() {
     RegistrationForm regForm = new RegistrationForm();
     /* init regForm */
     return regForm;
}
```

using populateForm method, you don't need to handle of creation of form backing objects yourself.

Comment: I'm no longer getting the server error, but the user isn't presented with a form validation error. I did set the message on the constraints: `@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your first name.")` and `@Size(min = 2, message = "It is highly unlikely that you have a one-letter name."`